# Apply list of functions to every column of data.table in R

Tags: r, data.table

I want to summarise a very large data table by applying a list of statistical functions to every column.
I want to use `data.table` as the previous version with `plyr` was working but quite slow and I read this should be much faster.
I tried the following but I get

```
Error in { : 
task 1 failed - "task 1 failed - "second argument must be a list""
```

Here are the functions I tried

```
library(data.table)
library(e1071)
library(nortest)    

statistical_tests = list(mean, sd, kurtosis, skewness,
                        lillie.test, shapiro.test)          

summary = function(column) {
    result = mapply(do.call, statistical_tests, column)
    print(result)
    return(result)
}

analyse_fits = function(fit_df) {
    #get mean and standard deviation for the three parameters
    print(fit_df)
    setkey(fit_df, type)
    return(fit_df[, lapply(.SD, summary),
        by=type])
}                                

analyse_fits(fit_df)
```

example data for `fit_df`:

```
    constant         phase visibility type
1: 49927.22 -2.609797e-03  0.8690605  fft
2: 49965.89 -6.783609e-05  0.8702492  fft
3: 50026.44 -1.109387e-03  0.8680235  fft
4: 50063.78  2.640915e-04  0.8697564  fft
5: 50074.89  9.999202e-04  0.8684974  fft
6: 49964.89 -2.075373e-03  0.8708830  fft
7: 50063.56 -9.737554e-04  0.8721360  fft
8: 50044.11 -1.920089e-03  0.8722035  fft
9: 50100.67 -7.487811e-04  0.8706438  fft
10: 49962.11  4.163415e-03  0.8713016  fft
11: 49926.63 -1.473941e-03  0.8687753   ls
12: 49964.98  1.794244e-03  0.8710003   ls
13: 50025.89 -1.315459e-03  0.8698475   ls
14: 50063.40  2.891339e-04  0.8699723   ls
15: 50074.70  1.859353e-03  0.8684841   ls
16: 49964.43 -6.426037e-04  0.8706581   ls
17: 50063.47 -1.646874e-03  0.8715316   ls
18: 50043.48 -1.435637e-03  0.8713584   ls
19: 50100.36 -2.261318e-03  0.8699203   ls
20: 49961.76  3.659428e-03  0.8704063   ls
```

I'm sure there a good way of formatting the output to make it work, can you help me?

Comment: As Carl said, it seems that you're calling one of the functions incorrectly. For the `base` functions, this works, anyway: `DT[,c(list(stat=c('mean','sd')),lapply(.SD,function(x)c(mean(x),sd(x)))),by=type].`

Answer (score 1):

First:  use `traceback()` to find out which function you are calling incorrectly.  That will help you properly format the inputs.

Second:  if you are always calling the same set of stats functions, it'll be easier just to write a "wrapper" function (see, e.g., my `cgwtools::mystat` toy) which explicitly calls each stats function in turn.

Answer (score 1):

I combined the approaches from Frank and Carl to write a named wrapper function and a list of names, and adding a "stat" column which I think is a neat idea.

```
statistical_tests = function(x) {
    return(c(
                mean(x),
                sd(x),
                kurtosis(x),
                skewness(x),
                lillie.test(x)$p.value,
                shapiro.test(x)$p.value))
}

names = c("mean", "sd",
        "kurtosis", "skewness",
        "normality.p.value.lilliefors",
        "normality.p.value.shapiro")

analyse_fits = function(fit_df) {
    #get mean and standard deviation for the three parameters
    setkey(fit_df, type)
    result = fit_df[, c(list(stat=names), lapply(.SD, statistical_tests)), by=type]
    setkeyv(result, c("stat", "type"))
    return(result)
}
```

Comment: +1 I haven't run or tested but just looking at it, for speed, it's normally best to keep `j` as simple as possible and take out any constants from it (e.g. the `stat=names` part), then reshape/name afterwards. Or maybe just see how much faster `fit_df[,lapply(.SD,statistical_tests),by=type]` is first to see if it's worth rearranging it.